# How to import a large and complex csproj into MonoDevelop 5.10 with Ubuntu 16.04 and the ASP.NET addin?

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I would like to know how to import a large and complex csproj into
MonoDevelop 5.10 with Ubuntu 16.04 and the ASP.NET addin.

I recently tried the method described in IanNorton's answer
to [open a .csproj with MonoDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9241351/3960947):

> Create a new empty solution and then copy your projects and their sources into the solution folder, then right click on the solution in the solution explorer and choose "Add > Add Existing Project".

This method works fine in production, but it is cumbersome in development where one is frequently making C# code changes and recompiling.

With this method, there are two directory hierarchies and file protection commands such as `chmod -R`, `chown -R` and `chgrp -R` to contend with in order to achieve a build with no errors and runs correctly with mod_mono_server4.

Furthermore, MonoDevelop pc files must be pointed at the imported project's directory tree with absolute pathnames which have to be changed
for each programmer's home directory.

I tried installing MonoDevelop pc files with relative pathnames into `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` today, to no avail. The problem is that one has to delete all the existing csproj Hint Paths first and reenter them manually in the csproj corresponding to the host project directory tree.

Another problem with MonoDevelop is that after it is successfully compiled, one has to reboot the Ubuntu 16.04 "box" every time.

My question is how to simplify this method to reduce the time consuming and the error prone aspects of it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There may not be a way to simplify this.

Comment: Why doesn't MonoDevelop rewrite the csproj HintPath upon reading the pc file from /usr/lib/pkgconfig? Thank you.

Comment: This is how to add ASP.NET add-in to Ubuntu 16.04 alpha release: https://brendaningram.com/article/how-to-fix-monodevelop-on-ubuntu-16-04/. Thank you.

Comment: Would an MonoDevelop expert have time to chat about this subject today for 8 minutes? Thank you.

Comment: Another problem with MonoDevelop is that after it is successfully compiled, one has to reboot the Ubuntu 16.04 "box".

Comment: @Moderator, Could you please reappraise this article? Thank you very much.

Comment: How much is a good bounty?

Comment: Another problem with MonoDevelop is that after it is successfully compiled, one has to reboot the Ubuntu 16.04 "box"  * only if * you are running mod_mono_server4.exe instead of xsp4.