# Is it possible to run 127.0.0.1/login.aspx at the web browser, if we run only one mod_mono_server4 and apache2 server instance on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, mono

Recently, I set up /etc/apache2/apache2.conf on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 so that an webuser can run 127.0.0.1/course/login.aspx with any browser  as long as we run 1 or more mod_mono_server4 server and 1 or more apache2 service instance.

> For the purpose of  making mod_mono handle multiple applications, it is necessary to put this at the end of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

```
  Alias /test "/var/www/firstaspnet" 
        Alias /personal "/var/www/thirdaspnet" 
        AddMonoApplications testing "/test:/var/www/firstaspnet" 
        AddMonoApplications organicchem "/personal:/var/www/thirdaspnet"       
    <Location /test>
              SetHandler mono
              MonoSetServerAlias testing   
    </Location> 
    <Location /personal>
             SetHandler mono
             MonoSetServerAlias organicchem 
    </Location>

>
```

Alternatively, for the purpose of  making mod_mono handle the web browser HTTPRequest 127.0.0.1//login.aspx, we put this at the end of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

```
MonoAutoApplication disabled
AddHandler mono .aspx .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx .axd
MonoApplications "/:/home/production/DevelopmentX64/My-Web-App/My-Web-App"
```

Is it possible to  run 127.0.0.1/login.aspx instead of 127.0.0.1/course/login.aspx at the web browser, if we run only one mod_mono_server4  and apache2 server instance on Ubuntu Linux 16.04? If that is correct, how should I set this up with /etc/apache2/apache2.conf on Ubuntu Linux 16.04?

> The reason I ask this question is that web users do not like typing
>   in longer URL's or understand why 127.0.0.1/course/login.aspx at the
>   web browser is necessary if we are running only one mod_mono_server4 
>   and apache2 server instance on Ubuntu Linux 16.04.

Any help is sincerely welcome and will be acknowledged through this
official channel promptly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to display 127.0.0.1/IPAddress.aspx and several(3) more on the first HTTPRequest try this afternoon before the request gets "cached" using the following Apache2.conf excerpt:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/vendors/DevelopmentX64/My-Web-App/My-Web-App"

ServerName localhost
LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mono.so

<Directory /home/vendors/DevelopmentX64/My-Web-App/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias "/" "/home/vendors/DevelopmentX64/My-Web-App/My-Web-App"


AddHandler mono .aspx .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx .axd
MonoApplications "/:/home/vendors/DevelopmentX64/My-Web-App/My-Web-App"
```